# How do I insert loaders to my inversifyjs project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, inversifyjs

I'm learning inversifyjs, and I'm trying to do the example from inversify package.
And I stumble upon an issue that you can see below:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (30:14)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| let Ninja = (_dec3 = injectable(), _dec3(_class3 = class Ninja {
>   constructor(@inject(TYPES.Weapon)
|   katana, @inject(TYPES.ThrowableWeapon)
|   shuriken) {
```

In this row `(30:14)` it does not recognise the `@` from `@inject(..)`.


How do I insert the loaders to my project for that to work?